# Execute command generated by a PHP script

Tags: command-line, bash, php

I have PHP file which has logic based on which I run either

```
bin/phpunit -c Application/app --testsuite $TESTSUITE
```

or

```
bin/phpunit -c Application/app --group group1 group2
```

when Im doing

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMAND=$(php travis_groups.php)
echo $COMMAND //bin/phpunit -c Application/app --testsuite $TESTSUITE
$COMMAND
```

Nothing happens but when I paste the command to sh file it works.

Why I can't I execute a command which is generated by a PHP script?

Edit:

Solution

```
eval $COMMAND
```

Comment: Is PHP in your $PATH?

Answer (score 0):

By `COMMAND=$(php travis_groups.php)` you just assign the command to `COMMAND` variable. If you want to run the command, you need to add `$COMMAND` after the assignment.



Simple example setup:

`echo.sh` file containing just line `echo "ls"`

`run_echoed.sh` file containing two lines:

```
COMMAND=$(bash echo.sh)
$COMMAND
```

When you run `run_echoed.sh` (either by `./run_echoed.sh` if the file is executable or `bash run_echoed.sh`), you print the directory contents (the `ls` command gets executed).

Of course make sure your `php travis_groups.php` actually prints out the commands (just run in the terminal). Otherwise you can't tell the other script what to assign to the variable.

Comment: Please look at my post I have  add missing code

Comment: So, to make it clear after your edit: `echo $COMMAND` returns the command all right, but running `$COMMAND` does nothing? Also, the line `echo $COMMAND //bin/phpunit -c Application/app --testsuite $TESTSUITE` is the actual line in your script?